# How to get only value from object. Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get a value from auth in laravel 8. But the only thing I got is just getting a specific attribute. Here's my code:

```
$user = auth()->user();
$tes = response()->json([
       'data' => $user->only(['id']),
]);

dd($tes);
```

Here's the response:

[image]

Can you guys tell me, how to get only value 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do

1. Helper Function

   ```
   $user = auth()->user();

   var_dump($user->id);
   ```
2. Using Facaade

   ```
   $user = Auth::user();

   var_dump($user->id);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`Auth` can return the user's id directly:

```
$userId = Auth::id();
$tes = response()->json([
       'data' => $userId,
]);

dd($tes);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$user = auth()->user();

$tes = response()->json([
  'data' => $user->id,
]);

dd($tes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified -

```
$tes = response()->json([
       'data' => Auth::id(),
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tes = response()->json([
       'data' => auth()->id()
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are right, but it will work for the case of the User model as Auth uses the User model.

In case you want it on any other model, use pluck() of Laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck